# UIImageView returns to original position when image is set - tvOS

Tags: swift, uiimageview, autolayout, tvos

I am using Swift and building a tvOS app.

So, I have one UIImageView called `imageView` that has constraints and is set to be in the center of the screen with about 80% width and height of the view.

When `viewDidAppear` is called, I change its frame to be **off the screen**: `imageView.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.width, imageView.frame.minY, imageView.frame.width, imageView.frame.height)`

When I click my remote, I set its image: `imageViewTwo.image = UIImage(named: "1")`

**PROBLEM:** When `imageView.image` is set to my image, it sets the frame of the UIImageView back to its original position, which is centered on the view. I do not want this. I want to set its image and for it to stay OFF the screen.

Does anybody know what's going on here? Or how I can get my desired result? Very confusing. All help is much appreciated!

Comment: Thanks for the edit!

Comment: When using Auto Layout, we do not deal with the frame directly, so if you want move the image view off the screen, you should modify the constraints instead of setting the frame.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this in change in method

```
viewDidLayoutSubviews
```

This method is called AFTER AutoLayout. ViewDidAppear is executed BEFORE Autolayout

Comment: Okay I'll try that. I found that setting `translatesAutoResizingMaskIntoConstraints` to True solved the problem, but causes constraint errors to print in the console. I'm going to try your suggestion real quick, will report back.